# How to colo(u)r dynamically created panels?

Tags: delphi

I declare a panel `ToolStatusPanel2` at design time and want to add 10 panels which represent a status, shown by the colour.

Now, my main form declares

```
 ToolOnlineStatusPanel : Array[0..Pred(NUM_TOOLS)] of TPanel;
```

and my `FormCreate` wants to set them to default color to `clRed` by

```
for i:= 0 to Pred(NUM_TOOLS) do
begin
  ToolOnlineStatusPanel[i] := TPanel.Create(ToolStatusPanel2);
  ToolOnlineStatusPanel[i].Parent := ToolStatusPanel2;
  ToolOnlineStatusPanel[i].Height := 16;
  ToolOnlineStatusPanel[i].Width := 16;
  ToolOnlineStatusPanel[i].Top := 8 + (i * (16 + 8));
  ToolOnlineStatusPanel[i].Left := 8;
  ToolOnlineStatusPanel[i].Color := clRed;
end;
```

but these child panels always have the same colo(u)r as their parent, even if I change that - never red.

Obviously I am overlooking something fairly simple. What is it? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set [`ParentBackground`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/API:Vcl.ExtCtrls.TPanel.ParentBackground) to False.